# python : threading.Timer is not getting called after specified time

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, celery

I have piece of code similar to following

```
class Job():
  def start():
    from threading import Timer
    t = Timer(10.0, self.cancel)
    t.start()
    self.status = "Started"
    submitChildTasks() #----> Submits child celery tasks
```

A job instance itself is a celery task and can have multiple child celery Tasks. I need to cancel Job and all its child tasks executing. for that I need to execute `cancel`. I Suspect that as soon as `Job.start()` finishes `t` is dying. is there any way to handle it. I want to have child tasks executing as well while 't' is waiting to execute `cancel`.
But `cancel` is not getting called. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Any guidance is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: your code is working properly !!! there might be some other problem could you provide more details?

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't post all the code I've added this code which is mainly the code you didn't post

```
from threading import Timer

def cancel():
    print 'cancel called'

t = Timer(10.0, cancel)
t.start()
```

This code will wait 10 seconds in the timer as expected. Perhaps the problem related to the missing class? Please add your code if this still not helping.